# How do I get Explorer to default to Folder Path instead of Folder when I search?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-search

Whenever I run a search in Explorer on Windows 7, the first thing I do is remove the Folder column and then add the Folder Path column. Is there a way to save this configuration so that this becomes the default? I went into Tools > Folder Options, but I didn't see a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<kbd>Tools</kbd>, <kbd>Folder Options</kbd>, <kbd>View</kbd>, <kbd>Apply to Folders</kbd>

Comment: Just tried this in Windows 10.  It seems the 'Apply to Folders' option is greyed out when accessed from search results. :-(

Comment: @TravisBemrose The option is grayed under Windows 8 as well.